# What branch of Economics does 'e-governance' fall under?

Tags: reference-request, government

I need to work on a project regarding e-governance in a region of India, and, I need to consult professors in education institutes who would have knowledge in this subject. So, for that I need to know what part of Economics does e-governance come under?

Does it come under Development Economics, Public Economics or any other field?

Answer (score 1):

This is **Public Economics**, under the [JEL code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JEL_classification_codes) H11:

[image]

Examples of such papers on e-Governance using the H11 JEL code are:

- https://ideas.repec.org/a/ekz/ekonoz/2003311.html
- http://www.sobiad.org/ejournals/journal_ijebeg/arhieves/2009/01ajay_kr_singh.pdf
- https://ideas.repec.org/p/cpr/ceprdp/11761.html
- https://ideas.repec.org/a/eco/journ3/2016-04-38.html
- https://ideas.repec.org/p/wiw/wiwrsa/ersa14p905.html

Note that papers usually have multiple JEL codes. That is the case of the last three papers given above. Some also use codes related to Economic Development (Under JEL codes O), if they refer to developing countries. **But the common denominator is Public Economics**.